# Most Pythonic way to merge two dictionnaries having common key/value pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two lists of python dictionnaries :

```
l1 = [{"id":1, "name":"A"}, {"id":2, "name":"B"}]
l2 = [{"id":1, "full_name":"Alfred"}, {"id":2, "full_name":"Barbara"}]
```

My goal is to have a list as follow :

```
l3 = [{"id":1, "full_name":"Alfred", "name":"A"}, {"id":2, "full_name":"Barbara", "name":"B"}]
```

I think I could use nested loops to do this, but I'm sure it should be possible to do it in a better and more pythonic way.

Comment: Are the lists already sorted by id, and the the ids in both lists known to be the same?

Comment: not always, it depends

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (take union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-take-union-of-dictionari)

Comment: No, because i need to be able to match the dictionnaries by their id too

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict


res = defaultdict(dict)
for a, b in zip(l1, l2):
    key1 = a['id']
    key2 = b['id']
    res[key1].update(a)
    res[key2].update(b)

print(list(res.values())) # [{'id': 1, 'name': 'A', 'full_name': 'Alfred'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'B', 'full_name': 'Barbara'}]
```

Although this would work in a single iteration you might want to simplify your underlying data structures a bit to make them easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

In one line (assuming id fields have perfect 1:1 mapping) :

```
result = [x | y for x, y in zip(sorted(l1, key = lambda x: x['id']), sorted(l2, key = lambda x: x['id']) )]
```

Comment: Does not work if the ids do not have a perfect 1:1 mapping.

Comment: Took it for granted, my bad. Thanks, edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you `sort` the lists by the ID value in advance and that the ID values in the two lists are the same (just possibly in a different order), we can do it with a simple `zip` call.

```
l1.sort(key=lambda x: x["id"])
l2.sort(key=lambda x: x["id"])

def merge(x, y):
    a = {}
    a.update(x)
    a.update(y)
    return a

l3 = [merge(x, y) for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Note that in Python 3.9 and newer, `merge` is simply `|`, so we can write

```
l3 = [x | y for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
```

and eliminate the need for the helper function altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest restructuring your input data when creating it, so that `id` is an actual identifier for each specific person. If you make value of `id` key for an outer dictionary, you can do it in a single pass through one each of the mappings.

```
from collections import defaultdict
l1 = {1:{"name":"A"}, 2:{"name":"B"}, 3:{"name":"C"}}
l2 = {1:{"full_name":"Alfred"}, 2:{"full_name":"Barbara"}}

result = defaultdict(dict)

for li in [l1, l2]:
    for k,v in li.items():
        result[k].update(v)

print(result)
```

(I removed the `"id":value` from the data because it's redundant with this form of data but adding it back in should be no problem if you really need it there.)

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [{"id":1, "name":"A"}, {"id":2, "name":"B"}]
l2 = [{"id":1, "full_name":"Alfred"}, {"id":2, "full_name":"Barbara"}]


print([{**i,**j} for i in l1 for j in l2 if i["id"] ==j["id"]])
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'A', 'full_name': 'Alfred'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'B', 'full_name': 'Barbara'}]
```

you could try something like this, which you maybe already knew ... would be interesting to see something more pythonic :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the id as identifer, create new dicts and update them - more comments in code.

No sorting needed, un"even" source lists inner dicts will be kept as well

```
l1 = [{"id":1, "name":"A"}, {"id":2, "name":"B"}]
l2 = [{"id":1, "full_name":"Alfred"}, {"id":2, "full_name":"Barbara"}]

# intermediate dictionary that keeps all collected inner dicts at the id
d = {}
# go through both lists
for inner_d in l1 + l2:
    # create a new empty dict under the id if needed 
    what = d.setdefault(inner_d["id"], {})
    # add all things from the inner dict
    what.update(inner_d.items())

as_list = list(d.values())
print(as_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'A', 'full_name': 'Alfred'}, 
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'B', 'full_name': 'Barbara'}]
```